# Multiple MYSQLI insert with data from arrays

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I need help figure this out. I need to run MYSQLI INSERT sevral times and insert data form array.

I get data from a form with two dynamic values a date span and a number that comes from the end user input. I need to insert this into a table in my database. The data from the secound array needs to be inserted on all the days in the first array.

FIRST ARRAY  Array ( [0] => 2020/01/26 [1] => 2020/01/27 [2] => 2020/01/28 [3] )

SECOND ARRAY  Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => )

This is what I expect to insert into my database:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE ('bookingdate', 'squarenumber',) VALUES (2020/01/26,1)
INSERT INTO MYTABLE ('bookingdate', 'squarenumber',) VALUES (2020/01/26,2)
INSERT INTO MYTABLE ('bookingdate', 'squarenumber',) VALUES (2020/01/26,3)

INSERT INTO MYTABLE ('bookingdate', 'squarenumber',) VALUES (2020/01/27,1)
INSERT INTO MYTABLE ('bookingdate', 'squarenumber',) VALUES (2020/01/27,2)
INSERT INTO MYTABLE ('bookingdate', 'squarenumber',) VALUES (2020/01/27,3)

INSERT INTO MYTABLE ('bookingdate', 'squarenumber',) VALUES (2020/01/28,1)
INSERT INTO MYTABLE ('bookingdate', 'squarenumber',) VALUES (2020/01/28,2)
INSERT INTO MYTABLE ('bookingdate', 'squarenumber',) VALUES (2020/01/28,3)
```

Can anyone help me? This got a bit to hard for me...

```
FORM 
<div id="massbooking-form-wrapper">
    <div class="massbooking-form-select-squares-wrapper">
        <h2>Välj rutor på område:<br> <?php echo getAreaname($link, $sq_areas_id); ?></h2>
        <br><br>
        <form name="booking_form" id="booking_form" action="<?php echo $bookingHomeUrl;?>/modules/bookings/process-massbooking.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group" >
                <label>Startdatum<label>
                <input type="text" disabled name="booking_from_date_to_post"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $booking_from_date?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" >
                <label>Slutdatum<label>
                <input type="text" disabled  name="booking_to_date_to_post" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $booking_to_date?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Rutor:</label>
                <input type="text" name="squarename_fill" id="squarename_fill" class="form-control" value="">   
            </div>

            <input type="text" hidden name="booking_from_date_to_post" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $booking_from_date?>">
            <input type="text" hidden name="booking_to_date_to_post" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $booking_to_date?>">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="return submitBookingConfirm()" value="Boka">
                <a class="btn btn-warning float-right" href="<?php echo $bookingHomeUrl;?>/welcome.php">Avbryt</a>
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default float-right" value="Rensa allt.">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div> 
</div>

    Getting all the dates in the span 

        function getDatesFromRange($start, $end, $format = 'Y/m/d') {
        /**
         * Generate an array of string dates between 2 dates
         */
            $array = array();
            $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');

            $realEnd = new DateTime($end);
            $realEnd->add($interval);

            $period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($start), $interval, $realEnd);

            foreach($period as $date) { 
                $array[] = $date->format($format); 
            }
            return $array;
        }

    print_r (getDatesFromRange($booking_from_date_to_post, $booking_to_date_to_post));
    echo '<br>';echo '<br>';

//Converting squares from string to array
$splitSquarename_fill = explode(',', $squarename_fill);
print_r($splitSquarename_fill);
```

Comment: can you share the POST variables or form at least ???

Comment: Which part exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really explained what you have a problem with. The SQL you showed is not the correct syntax, so I assume you were struggling with the right SQL syntax. The insert statement in MySQLi for this is not difficult, all you have to do is loop on both arrays and execute the statement for each value.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO MYTABLE (bookingdate, squarenumber) VALUES(?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $bookingdate, $squarenumber);
foreach ($array1 as $bookingdate) {
    foreach ($array2 as $squarenumber) {
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```